# ECS cluster cannot use KMS key to decrypt "you are not allowed to access"

Tags: amazon-iam, amazon-kms

I continue to get the error:

`software.amazon.awssdk.services.kms.model.KmsException: The ciphertext refers to a customer master key that does not exist, does not exist in this region, or you are not allowed to access.`

When attempting to decrypt.

I've created a Task execution role with the permission:

```
"AssumeRolePolicyDocument": {
      "Version": "2008-10-17",
      "Statement": [
        {
          "Effect": "Allow",
          "Principal": {
            "Service": "ecs-tasks.amazonaws.com"
          },
          "Action": "sts:AssumeRole"
        }
      ]
    },
    "ManagedPolicyArns": [
      "arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/service-role/AmazonECSTaskExecutionRolePolicy"
    ],
    "Policies": [
      {
        "PolicyName": "AllowKmsDecrypt",
        "PolicyDocument": {
          "Version": "2012-10-17",
          "Statement": [
            {
              "Effect": "Allow",
              "Action": [
                "kms:Decrypt"
              ],
              "Resource": [
                {"Ref": "PrincipalSourceKeyArn"}
              ]
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    ]
```

And the task definition is associated with the role:

```
        "ExecutionRoleArn": {"Ref": "TaskExecutionRoleArn"},
```

Hm. What else could i be missing?

Answer (score 3):

From these [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/kms/latest/developerguide/key-policies.html) it turns out an IAM policy is not sufficient:

> IAM policies by themselves are not sufficient to allow access to a
>   CMK. However, you can use them in combination with a CMK's key policy
>   if the key policy enables it. Giving the AWS account full access to
>   the CMK does this; it enables you to use IAM policies to give IAM
>   users and roles in the account access to the CMK

I needed to update the KMS `KeyPolicy` to include:

```
{
          "Sid": "Enable IAM User Permissions",
          "Effect": "Allow",
          "Principal": {
            "AWS": { "Fn::Join" : ["" , ["arn:aws:iam::", {"Ref" : "AWS::AccountId"} ,":root" ]] }
          },
          "Action": "kms:*",
          "Resource": "*"
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

In case of this line
`{ "Fn::Join" : ["" , ["arn:aws:iam::", {"Ref" : "AWS::AccountId"} ,":root" ]] }`
you are allowing to use this key by root account only.

Usually, this key policy has to provide manage possibilities for users and only a few specific actions for services or other users that use this key. So as for me the whole set up has to look something like this:

```
KMSKeyEncryption:
    Type: AWS::KMS::Key
    Properties:
      Enabled: true
      EnableKeyRotation: false
      KeyPolicy:
        Version: 2012-10-17
        Statement:
          - Principal:           
              AWS:arn of the users/roles who are allowed to manage this key
            Effect: Allow
            Action:
              - kms:Create*
              - kms:Describe*
              - kms:Enable*
              - kms:List*
              - kms:Put*
              - kms:Update*
              - kms:Revoke*
              - kms:Disable*
              - kms:Get*
              - kms:Delete*
              - kms:ScheduleKeyDeletion
              - kms:CancelKeyDeletion
              - kms:Encrypt*
              - kms:Decrypt*
            Resource: "*"
          - Principal: "*" # this is not specific enough, should be strict
            Effect: Allow
            Action:
              - kms:Decrypt*
            Resource: "*"
  PolicyDecryptKms:
    Type: AWS::IAM::ManagedPolicy
    Properties:
      ManagedPolicyName: DecryptKmsPolicy
      PolicyDocument:
        Version: '2012-10-17'
        Statement:
          - Sid: AllowDecryptValues
            Effect: Allow
            Action:
              - kms:Decrypt*
            Resource: !GetAtt KMSKeyEncryption.Arn
  RoleECSTaskContainer:
    Type: AWS::IAM::Role
    Properties:
      AssumeRolePolicyDocument:
        Version: 2008-10-17
        Statement:
          - Effect: Allow
            Principal:
              Service: ecs-tasks.amazonaws.com
            Action: sts:AssumeRole
      RoleName: ECSTaskContainerRole
      ManagedPolicyArns:
        - !Ref PolicyDecryptKms
```